# Restore Purchase in iOS InApp Purchase

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, in-app-purchase

I am developing a magazine app which has `autorenewable` subscription.I have implemented the purchase method and doin the validation using the receipt.My doubt are

1 .  How to know whether the subscription has expired or not from the receipt
2 .  How to restore the purchases or downloaded contents to another device .Currently my own server is providing the contents to download.So If I purchased some magazines in January and February, then if I try to restore the purchase  in another device in march,how could I restore the downloaded contents or check with my server to download the previously downloaded contents.The receipt contains only product ID and nothing related or unique to user , to handle users in `server` so that the downloads and restore can be handled from the server.

Thanks.Looking forward for expert help.

Answer (score 0):

Each user's device can obtain a receipt and either hand that receipt to your server or decode it and hand the results to your server. Your server will then respond to that device by downloading whatever it is entitled to receive.  The receipt contains all of the purchases made under that account and the dates the purchases were made so you should be able to figure out the active time of the subscription.  You could also use the 'expires_date' if the question is only whether the subscription is currently active.

If a device needs to prove that its subscription is valid it first tells the user that it needs to check on its subscription and then it executes either a restoreCompletedTransactions or a SKReceiptRefreshRequest.